# Taylor series for a complex function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 - 1}$ center at z=2

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I was trying to find the taylor serie for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 - 1}$ center at z=2 using $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}(a)\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}$$

However, it seems really hard. I didn't find the "series" for $f,f',f'',f'''...$

I found that I can use the geometric series. I read that $$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$

I know that $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} = f(z) = \frac{1}{(z - 1)(z + 1)}$$
Thus, is it correct to say that $$\frac{1}{(z - 1)(z + 1)}  = \frac{1}{(z+1)} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \cdot\frac{1}{(z+1)}$$

Any help for for the rest will be appreciate.

Edit: I just saw that my function is $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and not $\frac{1}{-z + 1}$, so probably all I did is wrong.

Comment: How about using partial fractions?  $f(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1} \right)$.

Comment: I didn't remember...
@DanielSchepler so, $$\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k - \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)z^k)$$
However, this the the series centered at z=0, right?

Comment: @Redwaves Recenter them before you expand them as a series, for instance $\frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{(z-2)+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial fraction approach works:

$$f(z)=\frac1{z^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)$$
You can either compute $f^{(n)}(2)$ from here, or you can let $w=z-2.$ Then:

$$\frac1{z^2-1}=\frac12\left(\frac1{w+1}-\frac{1}{w+3}\right)$$
Then:
$$
\begin{align} 
\frac1{w+1}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nw^n\\
\frac1{w+3}&=\frac1{3}\frac1{1+\frac w3}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}w^n
\end{align}
$$